# How to change number of rows in a <textarea> rendered by Wagtail's form builder

Tags: wagtail

I've created a form using Wagtail's form builder that includes a Multi-line text item.  When the `<textarea>` element is rendered, it renders with `rows="10"`.  I need to have fewer rows but don't see anything in the documentation about how to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Quick Solution

- Create a class that extends the `FormBuilder` from `wagtail.contrib.forms.forms`
- In this `CustomFormBuilder` class override the method `create_multiline_field`
- This method should return a [Django Form Field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/fields/)
- By default the widget used is [`Textarea`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Textarea) and the [default html `attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#Textarea) are cols: 40 & rows: 10
- In the overridden method, pas in any custom attrs you need e.g. `attrs = {'cols': '20', 'rows': '20'}`
- Finally, ensure that your `FormPage` has the `form_builder` set to the `CustomFormBuilder` class.
- Full code snippet below, this will make ALL multi-line form fields the same

```py
from django.db import models
import django.forms

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

from wagtail.contrib.forms.forms import FormBuilder
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import AbstractEmailForm, AbstractFormField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, FieldRowPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', related_name='form_fields', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class CustomFormBuilder(FormBuilder):

    def create_multiline_field(self, field, options):
        attrs = {'cols': '20', 'rows': '20'} # default attrs = {'cols': '40', 'rows': '10'}
        return django.forms.CharField(widget=django.forms.Textarea(attrs=attrs), **options)


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    form_builder = CustomFormBuilder # added - allows us to override the default FormBuilder

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
      #... InlinePanel etc
    ]
```

### More Generic Solution

- Building on the code above, we have to options, make the widget attributes customisable per field or per page, all have their pros and cons but lets go with each form field can customise their own attributes.
- Below we have added a new `StreamField` to the `FormField` that lets us add any arbitrary key/value pairs we can use as HTML attributes.
- The form page editing is not affected too much as the new 2.7 StreamField design is quite minimal.
- We then need to read this data for the field in our overridden `create_multiline_field` method.
- Note: the example below ONLY passes the attributes to a multiline field, you would need to override EACH form field method if you wanted to pass attributes into each of their widgets.

```py
from django.db import models
import django.forms

from modelcluster.fields import ParentalKey

from wagtail.core import blocks
from wagtail.core.fields import StreamField
from wagtail.contrib.forms.forms import FormBuilder
from wagtail.contrib.forms.models import AbstractEmailForm, AbstractFormField
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel, FieldRowPanel, InlinePanel, MultiFieldPanel, StreamFieldPanel


class FormField(AbstractFormField):
    attributes = StreamField([
        ('attributes', blocks.StructBlock([
            ('name', blocks.CharBlock()),
            ('value', blocks.CharBlock()),
        ])),
    ], blank=True)

    page = ParentalKey('FormPage', related_name='form_fields', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    panels = AbstractFormField.panels + [
        StreamFieldPanel('attributes'),
    ]


class CustomFormBuilder(FormBuilder):

    def create_multiline_field(self, field, options):
        # note - to accept attrs - ALL form field methods will need to be updated

        attributes = field.attributes
        attributes_data = attributes.get_prep_value() # convert the streamfield value into a Python data structure
        # outputs [{'value': {'value': '5', 'name': 'rows'}, 'id': '6cb7d669-626c-47c0-bcac-5d982e5d9209', 'type': 'attributes'}]

        keys = [_.get('value').get('name') for _ in attributes_data]
        values = [_.get('value').get('value') for _ in attributes_data]
        attrs = dict(zip(keys, values))
        return django.forms.CharField(widget=django.forms.Textarea(attrs=attrs), **options)


class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):

    form_builder = CustomFormBuilder # added - allows us to override the default FormBuilder

    content_panels = AbstractEmailForm.content_panels + [
      #... InlinePanel etc
    ]
```

Comment: I went with the quick solution, and it worked.  Thank you @LB Ben Johnston.  Just one thing for anyone else who might come across this - I am actually using WagtailCaptchaForm so had to do: from wagtailcaptcha.forms import WagtailCaptchaFormBuilder and then inherit from WagtailCaptchaFormBuilder in the CustomFormBuilder declaration.